# Navigation drawer home icon does not restore to hamburger icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have made a navigation bar by including a fragment inside the Drawer layout. Everything works, the drawer slides out from the left and everything.

When the application is opened for the first time, I see a hamburger icon. When I open it fully and close it back, the hamburger icon changes to a left arrow.

I am unable to figure out why this happening.

Here is the code:

Activity:

```
 // Drawer
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // toolbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Blah");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // navigation drawer
    NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    navigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, drawerLayout, toolbar);
```

setUp function called above:

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    this.navigationDrawerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
}
```

P.S: I am new to android programming. I followed a youtube tutorial to achieve this. I have a fair idea what is going on, but please (if possible) a little more descriptively so as to help me follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method **onDrawerClosed** is wrong. You're calling super.onDrawerOpened and have to be **super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);**

In this way

```
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
       super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
       getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have learnt my lesson. Never copy paste your code. I always forget to refactor something or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

into

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to set navigation with icons in the whole application, I am sure it will work for you.its simple method

mainActivity.java

```
getSupportActionBar().bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);//Doing so will make the icon appear


navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController navController, @NonNull NavDestination navDestination, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                if ( mAppBarConfiguration.getTopLevelDestinations().contains(navDestination.getId())){
                    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.yout_drawer_icon);
                } else {
                    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.you_back_icon);
                }
            }
        });
```